# changePage interfering with custom select

Tags: jquery-mobile

i have a select button on a jquery mobile page with a data-native-menu="false". The list of options is too long for a pop-up, that is why jqm uses a page overlay to show the select-menu.

i'd like to use this select menu for navigation, so i bind to the change event a changePage function.

here's what happens: i tap on a list item, the new page slides in and slides out again immediately. My guess is that this happens because the page overlay of the custom select menu wants to go back to the page it was invoked from ?!?

Any ideas to prevent this?

thank you in advance :-))

Here's my code

html:

```
            <div id="one" data-role="page" data-theme="a"> 
            <div >
            <div class="myHeader"></div>
            </div> 
            <div data-role="content"> 
            <div id="startbuttons">
            <a href="#two" data-role="button" data-theme="a" data-transition="slide">PREIS ERMITTELN</a>
            <select name="miet" id="miet" data-theme="b" data-native-menu="false" data-icon="false" data-iconpos="center" data-overlay-theme="b">
            <option data-placeholder="MIETSTATIONEN">MIETSTATIONEN</option>
            <option value="mietstation_dummy.html">HAMBURG</option>
            <option value="mietstation_dummy.html">BERLIN</option>
            <option value="mietstation_dummy.html">MÜNCHEN</option>
            <option value="mietstation_dummy.html">HAMBURG</option>
            <option value="mietstation_dummy.html">BERLIN</option>
            <option value="mietstation_dummy.html">MÜNCHEN</option>
            <option value="mietstation_dummy.html">HAMBURG</option>
            <option value="mietstation_dummy.html">BERLIN</option>
            <option value="mietstation_dummy.html">MÜNCHEN</option>
            <option value="mietstation_dummy.html">HAMBURG</option>
            <option value="mietstation_dummy.html">BERLIN</option>
            <option value="mietstation_dummy.html">MÜNCHEN</option>
            </select>
            </div>
            <p class="linktxt" data-theme="a">Oder besuchen Sie unsere<br><a data-theme="a" href="hmm.html">Standard-Website</a></p>
            <p class="linktxt kontakt"><a data-theme="a" href="hmm.html">Kontakt</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a data-theme="a" href="hmm.html">Impressum</a></p>
            </div> 
            </div>
```

js:

```
            $('#miet').change(function(event){

            var $vn = $('#miet').val();
            $.mobile.changePage(''+$vn, { transition: "slide"} );
            $('#miet').val('MIETSTATIONEN').selectmenu('refresh');

            return false;
            });
```

ps: if i set data-native-menu="true" it works like a charm (but i really like to use the custom select menu)

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure if this is what you are looking for (or if you actually solved it), but have a look at this guy's answer on a similar thing (the very last comment on the thread). It might point you in the right direction ;)

[JQuery Mobile changePage() flaky when called from dynamically created select option?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8698614/jquery-mobile-changepage-flaky-when-called-from-dynamically-created-select-opt)